# Dúvidas em relação a events mysql

Tags: mysql

Criei um evento em um banco de dados **MySql**, notei que quando eu reinicio o banco `localhost`, o evento volta `offline`, alguém sabe se é assim mesmo ou se tem que executar um comando sempre que o banco de dados for iniciado ou se estiver em uma hospedagem o banco já executa o comando após o banco ser reiniciado caso alguma queda ou por conta de manutenção?

Código usado para start do evento:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Código do evento:

```
CREATE EVENT `limpeza`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
insert into pessoa (nome) SELECT CONCAT_WS(":",CURRENT_DATE(),EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIME()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir

event_scheduler=ON

**no arquivo my.ini ou my.cnf ,** reinicie o servidor para que a configuração entre em vigor.

Uma vez definido, o event_scheduler permanecerá sempre ON não importando se o seu servidor é reiniciado.